# Compare display value with binding source value in DataGridView.CellFormatting?

Tags: c#, user-interface, datagridview, bindingsource

I am now using a plain DataGridView component to display data with my own implementation of IBindingSource interface. The columns are binded to properties.

Now I am trying to compare the current "display value" in the grid (i.e. the actual previous value) and the latest value in the IBindingSource to determine background of the cell. Is it correct to compare the Value on the event with the value like Grid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex] ? Or is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance.